# Дублирование проверки на null

Tags: c#, исключения, инспекция-кода, валидация

Один из методов бизнес-логики начинается с кода валидации:

```
public void Update(ProductDto dto)
{
    if (dto == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dto));
    }

    var validContext = new ValidationContext(dto);
    Validator.ValidateObject(dto, validContext);     

    //...
}
```

Если в метод передается `null`, то я выбрасываю стандартное исключение `ArgumentNullException` и **никакой дополнительной информации** как видите не отсылаю.

Мне кажется, что блок проверки на `null` **излишен**, потому что в случае `dto = null` следующее **за ним** выражение  `var validContext = new ValidationContext(dto)` так и так выбросит **то же самое** исключение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Будет ли ругаться "практика правильного дизайна", если я сокращу метод так?**

```
public void Update(ProductDto dto)
{
    var validContext = new ValidationContext(dto);
    Validator.ValidateObject(dto, validContext);  

    //...
}
```

Comment: вы в конструктор эксепшена null же передаете throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dto));

Comment: @LexHobbit, нет, передается имя параметра: [nameof](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof)

Comment: @Grundy тьфу nameof пропустил ... ОМГ

Comment: @LexHobbit да ты прав, когда я говорил, что никакой дополнительной информации не сообщаю, то лукавил - я сообщаю _имя нулевого аргумента_ чего не делает `ValidationContext`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Да, такое изменение я бы не назвал правильным.

Дело в том, что вы тем самым вносите в ваш метод *связность*. Ваш код будет правильным лишь в том случае, если

- конструктор `ValidationContext` проверяет входящий объект на `null`, и бросает исключение, и
- у вас до вызова этого конструктора нету другого кода, который использует `dto` или делает какую-то другую полезную работу.

Каждое из этих предположений нужно будет держать в голове, работая с данным кодом. Причём в коде придётся ещё и оставлять комментарий, который будет объяснять, что `null` не является валидным входным значением, и почему именно в этом месте нету проверки на `null`.

В противоположность этому проверка в начале является практически самодокументируемым кодом, она сразу говорит читателю, что нулевое входное значение неверно.

Чем *меньше* нужно держать в голове, тем лучше, и тем меньше вероятность ошибки.

---

Ещё одно мелкое соображение в пользу ранней проверки: если вы видите stack trace упавшего на `ArgumentNullException` приложения, то ошибка скорее всего находится в методе на один фрейм выше метода, бросившего исключение. В случае «пропуска» плохого аргумента в глубину это соображение не работает.

Comment: это типа как говорят матросы, чем больше бумаги, тем чище ...

Comment: @LexHobbit: Ну это да :)

Comment: С проверкой на `null` понятно. А что на счет валидации _свойств_ `объекта-параметр`. В данном примере у меня был _data transfer object_, а если на его месте была сама сущность _entity_ из базы данных? Дело в том, что у меня там использован database first и атрибуты валидации не поставить (edmx не хочет, чтобы его творение трогали). Как обеспечить валидацию _свойств_ подобных сущностей и нужно ли?

Comment: @adamshakhabov: Я не работал с EF, но мне кажется, принцип должен быть таков: для каждого (публичного) метода должно быть сформулировано (например, в документации или хотя бы в комментариях) то, какие значения являются валидными значениями параметров. И эта самая валидность параметров должна проверяться как можно раньше, в идеале — в самом начале метода. Как этот принцип соотносится с атрибутами валидации (и что такое эти самые _атрибуты валидации_) я, к сожалению, не в курсе.

Comment: Валидация -- это почти всегда некоторая бизнес-логика. Проверки аргументов -- это более "техническая" вещь, часть контракта метода.

Comment: @andreycha: Если так, то она часть флоу и должна быть вызвана явно в том или ином виде.

Comment: @andreycha, что-то Вы меня запутали. Проверка аргумента — это разве не часть валидации? И мне казалось, что проверка аргументов тоже логика, т.к. в некоторых случаях допустимое значение аргумента может завесить от значение другого параметра

Comment: @adamshakhabov валидация данных и валидация аргументов метода -- это разные вещи.

Answer (score 3):

Внесу краткое дополнение к ответу.

Не сложность заметить, что конструкции вида:

```
public void Update(ProductDto dto)
{
    if (dto == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dto));
    }

    //...
}
```

выглядят довольно громоздко и не эстетично, так и возникает желание избавиться от них. А потому одним из способов добиться этого, может стать использование **контрактов** (Code Contracts). Например, в случае их использования код выглядел бы так:

```
public void Update(ProductDto dto)
{
     // Определили Предусловие. Нарушение предусловия говорит о том, 
     // что клиент не прав. 
     Contract.Requires(dto != null);

    //...
}
```

Это не только сократит его и сделает чище, но а так же более явно выразит ваши требования.

Comment: Хорошо, что вспомнили про code contract. ТС советую почитать, чтобы понимать, зачем нужны проверки аргументов и почему их нужно "дублировать".

Comment: @andreycha ТС - это сокращение Тепляков Сергей? )

Comment: Это топик стартер. А Тепляков тут уже [рассказывал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458417/106) про контракты, кстати.

Comment: @andreycha не видел этот пост, спасибо. Теплякова всегда интересно читать.

Comment: А еще лучше пинать разработчиков шарпа, чтобы они не откладывали, а наконец ввели не-нулевые ссылочные типы.

Comment: @vitidev: Планируют к C#8: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/docs/Language%20Feature%20Status.md

Comment: @VladD Планировать - не значит сделать. Они до этого к c# 7 планировали. Да и делать это нужно было при создании языка, а сейчас по нормальному не сделать уже и придется мириться с кучей костылей.

Comment: @vitidev: Ну я ж не сказал «сделают». Ну и если честно, у меня нет возможности ускорить процесс или повлиять на список приоритетных фич, поэтому предлагаю быть им благодарными за то, что планируют. В конце-концов, могли бы и не планировать.

Comment: Дело даже не в фичах, то что востребовано будет реализовано рано или поздно в любом случае. Меня радует одно, то что язык не стоит на месте и развивается и это плюс.